# Audio doesn't time correctly

Tags: import, video-sequence-editor

So I made a small animation, and then I added in a simple "pow" sound in the Video Sequence editor.
But when I started it, the sound played immediately. I rewound it even more, and the sound doesn't play until a couple frames before the file, and If I pause and play it over and over near where the audio is, it restarts and plays the sound over and over, until I get to the sound, and there it stops sounding at all.
I don't know what could be causing this.
The sound is not playing where it is supposed to play.

Answer (score 1):

In the Timeline window -> `playback`, you must check "`Audio Scrubbing`" AND "`AV-Sync`". Does it resolves the problem ?

Comment: It made it a little better, but its still kinda off.